# JQuery-File-Upload Button dependencies

Tags: jquery

I am using this [application example](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example) and try to model it to fit my needs.

I am modelling your index.html.erb to fit my needs.
I want to get rid of "start" button in order to prevent single-file upload (I dont want it), but it seems that "start upload"(multiple upload)-button is on "start" button dependent and I could not find how to modify the script in order to get rid of "start"-buttom but to keep the functionality of a "start upload" -button.

Can you give me some hints how to get rid of those dependencies?

Hier is the short code cut-off:
I have marked the lines where "start upload" and "start" buttons are situated with !!!.

```
<div class="container">
      <h2>Upload file</h2>
      <%= form_for Upload.new, :html => { :multipart => true, :id => "fileupload" } do |f| %>
        <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
        <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
          <div class="span7">
            <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
              <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
              <span>Add files...</span>
              <%= f.file_field :upload %>
            </span>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
              <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
 !!!!            <span>Start upload</span>
            </button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
              <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
              <span>Cancel upload</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
              <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
              <span>Delete</span>
            </button>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
          </div>
          <div class="span5">
            <!-- The global progress bar -->
            <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active fade">
              <div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- The loading indicator is shown during image processing -->
        <div class="fileupload-loading"></div>
        <br>
        <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
        <table class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery"></tbody>
        </table>
      <% end %>

    </div>


    <!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
    <script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
      {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
      <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>
        <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        {% if (file.error) { %}
        <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
        {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
        <td>
          <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
        </td>
   !!!     <td class="start">{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
          <button class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
            <span>{%=locale.fileupload.start%}</span>
          </button>
          {% } %}</td>
        {% } else { %}
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="cancel">{% if (!i) { %}
          <button class="btn btn-warning">
            <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
            <span>{%=locale.fileupload.cancel%}</span>
          </button>
          {% } %}</td>
      </tr>
      {% } %}
    </script>
    <!-- The template to display files available for download -->
    <script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      $(function () {
          // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
          $('#fileupload').fileupload();
          //
          // Load existing files:
          $.getJSON($('#fileupload').prop('action'), function (files) {
            var fu = $('#fileupload').data('fileupload'),
              template;
            fu._adjustMaxNumberOfFiles(-files.length);
            console.log(files);
            template = fu._renderDownload(files)
              .appendTo($('#fileupload .files'));
            // Force reflow:
            fu._reflow = fu._transition && template.length &&
              template[0].offsetWidth;
            template.addClass('in');
            $('#loading').remove();
          });

      });
    </script>
```

Thank you.
Cheers, Katja